# How to parse Dante log file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, logparser, dante

I have a dante socks log file and trying to a way out to parse getting two parts and seperate them with a semicolon.

Log File contains:

```
Sep 11 03:02:00 (1568505720.145620) danted[10402]: info: pass(2): tcp/connect -: pam.username%MyUsername@46.111.111.250.48198 123.12.12.112.1080 -> 123.12.12.112.48198 111.123.123.147.443 (319721)
Sep 11 03:02:00 (1568505720.147471) danted[10402]: info: pass(2): tcp/connect -: pam.username%MyUsername@46.111.111.250.37449 123.12.12.112.1080 -> 123.12.12.112.37449 123.123.123.211.443 (312)
Sep 11 03:02:00 (1568505720.148240) danted[10402]: info: pass(2): tcp/connect -: 111.123.123.147.443 123.12.12.112.48198 -> 123.12.12.112.1080 pam.username%MyUsername@46.111.111.250.48198 (723)
Sep 11 03:02:00 (1568505720.154784) danted[10402]: info: pass(2): tcp/connect -: 123.123.123.211.443 123.12.12.112.37449 -> 123.12.12.112.1080 pam.username%MyUsername@46.111.111.250.37449 (8831)
```

Basicly, I want to get after **pam.username%** to fetch to username and data rate inside of two parenthesise like **8831** so end up something like below:

```
MyUsername;319721
MyUsername;312
MyUsername;723
MyUsername;8831
```

I guess awk and sed/regex knowledge would be great at that point.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

A perl way:

```
perl -ane 's/^.+?pam\.username%([^@]+).+?\((\d+).*$/$1;$2/;print' file.log
MyUsername;319721
MyUsername;312
MyUsername;723
MyUsername;8831
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following regex:

```
pam\.username%([A-Za-z0-9]+)@|\s\(([0-9]+)\)
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cToW35/5)

Explanation:

```
pam\.username%([A-Za-z0-9]+)@  # Match any A-Za-z0-9 between pam.username% and @ - Group 1
|                              # Or
\s\(([0-9]+)\)         # Match any digits between parenthesis following a whitespace - Group 2
```

Access the username via Group 1, and the data rate via Group 2.

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `awk`and `gensub` function of it, could you please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  regex=".*(pam.username%[^@]*).*\\((.*)\\)"
}
{
  val=gensub(regex, "\\1;\\2","1",$0)
  sub(/[^%]*%/,"",val)
  print val
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: @linuxman, Could you please do let me know if this solution helped you?